# Web-Service invoke with JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, web-services, jax-ws

I am developing my first Web-Service at the moment.

Client is developed with JavaScript.

My problem is that it did not work. I do not know what my problem is.

I think it is a mistake on the client site.
I tried it with an Java Web-Service Client and there it works.

Web-Service:

```
import javax.jws.*;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
@WebService(name="TicketWebService", targetNamespace = "http://my.org/ns/")
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.RPC)
public class TicketWebService {

  @WebMethod(operationName="getContact")
  public String getContact()
  {

     return "Hallo Hans!!!";
  }
}
```

Publish on Server:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

public class PublishWsOnServer
{
  public static void main( String[] args )
  {
    Endpoint endpoint = Endpoint.publish( "http://localhost:8080/services",
                                          new TicketWebService() );
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Server beenden" );
    endpoint.stop(); 
  }
}
```

Client:

```
 <html>
  <head>
   <title>Client</title>
    <script language="JavaScript">
function HelloTo()
{
    var endpoint = "http://localhost:8080/services";
    var soapaction = "http://localhost:8080/services/getContact";

    xmlHttp = getXMLHttp();
    xmlHttp.open('POST', endpoint, true);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml;charset=utf-8');
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('SOAPAction', soapaction);

    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

       alert(xmlHttp.responseXML);

    }

    xmlHttp.send(request);
}
</script>
    </head>
    <body onLoad="HelloTo()" id="service">
    Body in Client
  </body>
 </html>
```

The alert does not work...

Comment: You know whether the request reaches the client? Create some sample output in the service, e.g. System.out.println.

Comment: thanks for your answer...
I write a system.out.println in the method getContact()

Where should the output be stood?
I found it nowhere...

Comment: The output should be available in the console from which you start your Java Web Service (main[] method).

Comment: okey...
there is no output in de web-service console...
Do you have an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty new at JAX-WS but I think that maybe your problem is not in the client side. First of all, [here](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-hello-world-example/) you have a HelloWorld example that works fine, if you look into the code you will see that in the web service implementation the annotation WebService is defined as

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.mkyong.ws.HelloWorld")
```

which is the full package of your "TicketWebService". Another difference is that the example defines an interface (marked with the @WebService annotation) and then implements it, including the @WebService also in the implementation. I don't think this is mandatory, but is a good practice to define the interface.